# How to properly convert accents

Tags: python

I have a list of peoples names with accents in them however they have not been read properly in the python code, so it produces symbols in place for it.

```
['/Younghoon',
 '/Riley_Green',
 '/Peter_Popluh%C3%A1r',
 '/Finn_Wolfhard',
 '/Morteza_Pouraliganji',
 '/Cristi%C3%A1n_de_la_Fuente',
 '/Arturo_Carmona',
 '/Fabian_Arnold',
 '/Jack_Avery',
 '/Andres_Camilo',
 '/Utt%282%29',
 '/Eduardo_Barquin',
 '/Adri%C3%A1n_Lastra']
```

This should instead produce:

```
['/Younghoon',
 '/Riley_Green',
 '/Peter_Popluhár',
 '/Finn_Wolfhard',
 '/Morteza_Pouraliganji',
 '/Cristián_de_la_Fuente',
 '/Arturo_Carmona',
 '/Fabian_Arnold',
 '/Jack_Avery',
 '/Andres_Camilo',
 '/Utt%282%29',
 '/Eduardo_Barquin',
 '/Adrián_Lastra'
```

Where `Utt%282%29` does not need converting because these are links to a website page, and this is as is for the website name.

Comment: OK. So what is the question?

Comment: Using [__url-decode__](https://www.urldecoder.io/) leads to `/Utt(2)` for `/Utt%282%29`. How should the code know, that this needs to be excluded from decoding?

Comment: The data in your first example is data that has been read from a file encoded  in UTF-8 but has been interpreted as though it was Windows-1252. If you specify `encoding='UTF-8'` when you open that file then you won't have to do any transcontinental or conversion. That is a more straightforward solution than trying to undo the damage afterwards

Comment: @hc_dev seems that this conversion still works and directs to the correct html link

Comment: @Stackcans That's because you usually can type any characters inside the browser's address-bar or paste even URLs with space inside. The [browser will translate = URL-encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530173/why-browsers-encode-url-in-this-form) them. Even command-line tools, like _cURL_ or _wget_ do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%`-encoded strings are probably [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) (like usually done in URIs and URLs, because they must be ASCII-only).

To decode a URL-encoded string use [`urllib.parse.unquote(s)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote).

See also:
[Url decode UTF-8 in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566069/url-decode-utf-8-in-python)

```py
from urllib.parse import unquote

url_encoded_strings = ['/Younghoon',
    '/Riley_Green',
    '/Peter_Popluh%C3%A1r',
    '/Finn_Wolfhard',
    '/Morteza_Pouraliganji',
    '/Cristi%C3%A1n_de_la_Fuente',
    '/Arturo_Carmona',
    '/Fabian_Arnold',
    '/Jack_Avery',
    '/Andres_Camilo',
    '/Utt%282%29',
    '/Eduardo_Barquin',
    '/Adri%C3%A1n_Lastra']

decoded_strings = [unquote(s) for s in url_encoded_strings]

print('\n'.join(decoded_strings))
```

Gives following output:

```
/Younghoon
/Riley_Green
/Peter_Popluhár
/Finn_Wolfhard
/Morteza_Pouraliganji
/Cristián_de_la_Fuente
/Arturo_Carmona
/Fabian_Arnold
/Jack_Avery
/Andres_Camilo
/Utt(2)
/Eduardo_Barquin
/Adrián_Lastra
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue before , could you include ", **ensure_ascii=False**" when you are reading them. For example usage:
`with open("../example.json", "a", encoding="utf-8") as outfile: json_object = json.dumps(constJSON,indent = 2, ensure_ascii=False)               outfile.write(json_object)`